# Selenium-webdriver input.Actions is clicking on an element multiple times instead of once

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium-webdriver on a Windows 10 machine, with node 16.17.0, chromedriver 106.0.5249.61 and Chrome 106.0.5249.119

What I'm trying to do is, I have a `ul` element with a bunch of `li` inside, and I want to `CTRL+click` each element in the list in order to open them in a new tab. So I wrote this code to do that (only clicking on the first 3 elements for now for testing purposes)

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/div/ul/li[" + i + "]/div/div[1]/label/div/div[1]/a")), 10000)
    .then((r) => actions
            .keyDown(Key.CONTROL)
            .move({origin: r})
            .press()
            .release()
            .keyUp(Key.CONTROL)
            .perform())
    .then(() => console.log('hello'))
    .then(() => driver.sleep(200))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This code does open the first three elements in new tabs, but it also clicks on the same element multiple times. I always end up with six new tabs instead of three.

I added `console.log('hello')` and to my surprise it only gets printed three times. I also tried replacing

```
.move({origin: r})
.press()
.release()
```

with a simple

```
.click(r)
```

but I'm getting the same result.

Any idea what's happening? I'm also happy just finding another way to open a link in a new tab. Thanks

Comment: You have to click on the dropdown list(to expand the list). Then click on the 1st option. Then click on the dropdown list again(to expand the list). And then click on the 2nd option.

Comment: The list in question isn't a dropdown though, there is nothing to expand

Comment: Can you add the DOM structure without data?